# Regexp for array of numbers both float and integers separated by comma

Tags: regex, qt, qregexp

I have to limit the data entered in the text box using the regexp for the following:
Exs:

- 1,2,3
- 2.2,3.1,3

and if the user leaves the text box after entering 1.2,2,3. I have to remove the dot after 3 and save.

I started of restricting to enter only dot or comma with the regexp **"([.,]{1})"**
but the text box accepts one dot whereas it allows to enter 3 commas.

Comment: So, you want to allow a trailing dot with the regex? Use [`^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*(,[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/Lkhugb/1)

Comment: Or do you mean you only allow that dot at the end of the string only? Try `^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?(,[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?)*[.]?$`, then check if the string `endsWith` the `.` and `truncate` it.

Comment: the trailing dot is nothing but if the user forgets to complete float value and stops with the dot then it has to be detected and igonred. And also i am not restricting the user to enter only 3 such values. It can be n number of values.

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what you need. The question sounds unclear without your code and exact real life scenario descriptions. If you need regex help, please narrow down the question. My regexps above do not restrict to only 3 values, `*` means *zero or more occurrences*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew with your help, i tried this (^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*[,]?${1,})           but it accepts only once i.e 1.2, not able to continue like 1.2,2.3 like that

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. I didnt understand the () part now it's clear. But why {1,} this doesn't work? This also says the entire exp can happen atleast once right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128817/discussion-between-xavier-geoffrey-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: *But why {1,} this doesn't work?* - you put it after `$` and thus quantified the end of string. Nonsense - there is only 1 end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

For the regex itself follow the advice  of Wiktor Stribiżew

Do you know QRegexValidator ?
For the validation of data entered in a textbox the best way is to use a QRegexValidator

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexpvalidator.html#details

```
// regexp: optional '-' followed by between 1 and 3 digits
QRegExp rx("-?\\d{1,3}");
QValidator *validator = new QRegExpValidator(rx, this);

QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit(this);
edit->setValidator(validator);
```

Using this object the user **can't** enter a non valid data in the field so you **don't** have to process something when the user leaves the text box

Comment: yes i am aware of. Unfortunately I am in a position not to use it.